# Problema con el campo DATETIME en MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

En mi base de datos MySQL en phpMyAdmin tengo una tabla en la que cuando introduzco una fecha en un campo de la tabla se me pone la fecha en formato con milisegundos.

Al pulsar encima del campo para seleccionar una fecha del calendario me aparece de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con la barra para seleccionar los milisegundos. Y si selecciono un día cualquiera, el campo se guarda de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a cambiar la configuración de la tabla y eliminar y volver a crear el campo pero sigue ocurriendo lo mismo. Me ocurre en cualquier campo de tipo `DATETIME`.

Ésta es la configuración de esta tabla en concreto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué puede estar ocurriendo?

Comment: Cambia el campo DATETIME por uno de tipo DATE, así no almacenaras hora, fecha y segundos.

Comment: ¿En qué formato quieres la fecha? ¿Sólo fecha? ¿Fecha y hora?

Comment: Fecha y hora (YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss)

Comment: Necesito almacenar hora, minutos y segundos, pero en formato YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss. Ej) 2018-05-20 02:09:23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que sufres es debido a que has definido el campo usando un parámetro entre paréntesis (o quizá a través de un editor de tablas o GUI que te agregó ese valor).

Si defines un campo con [`DATETIME(6)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html) los campos de fecha tendrán 6 cifras decimales:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  fecha DATETIME(6)
);
```

Para crear correctamente la tabla debes usar `DATETIME` sin ningún valor entre paréntesis o bien un valor `(0)` para indicar "0 cifras decimales":

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  fecha DATETIME(0)
);
```

Para cambiar la definición sin perder los datos almacenados en la tabla puedes usar:

```
ALTER TABLE test
  MODIFY fecha DATETIME(0);
```

Si lo que quieres es únicamente año, mes y día entonces debes usar un tipo [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) en su lugar:

```
ALTER TABLE test
  MODIFY fecha DATE;
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo en línea en [este enlace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6i7KReU7ewJ3pTm4vEKCp6/0).

Comment: Creé la tabla en phpmyadmin. He hecho el ALTER TABLE test
  MODIFY fecha DATETIME(0); pero me sigue ocurriendo lo mismo.

Comment: ¿Podrías exportar el esquema de la tabla y decirme cuál es la definición? Usa para ello `SHOW CREATE TABLE alm_boletines`.

Comment: Haciendo eso no me aparece nada. Solo el nombre del campo de la bbdd

Comment: ¿"Sólo el nombre de la bbdd" qué es? ¿Podrías decirme si estás usando la pestaña "SQL" de phpMyAdmin para ejecutar esa consulta SQL? Si es así, ¿estás dentro de la base de datos? Si no es así debes indicarlo explícitamente con `SHOW CREATE TABLE bbdd.tabla`, donde `bbdd` es el nombre de la base de datos y `tabla` el nombre de la tabla. Debería salirte un único registro con la instrucción `CREATE TABLE` necesaria para recrear la tabla. En esa información aparece qué tipo de dato es cada campo y es lo que necesito comprobar.

Comment: Te he dejado un ejemplo de cómo funciona y cómo debe verse en este enlace: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6i7KReU7ewJ3pTm4vEKCp6/1](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6i7KReU7ewJ3pTm4vEKCp6/1)

Comment: Edito la pregunta para mostrar lo que realizo

Answer (score 0):

A respuesta de tu pregunta yo tenía el mismo problema , lo solucione seleccionando now [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen y me salió la consulta sin modificar nada ni insertar nada ya tenía la hora y minutos introducir la descripción de la imagen aquíaquí]

Comment: Lee [answer]. ¿Qué es `NOW`? Recuerda que no todos pueden ver las imágenes, así que sé lo más descriptivo posible cuando respondes. Además, debes utilizar imágenes _recortadas_, o mejor aún, capturas de pantalla desde la propia computadora, o mucho mejor: _no usar imágenes_ :) Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Y me mostró la consulta sql sin insertar nada ignora ya ese icono de fecha solo selecciona Now cómo la imagen anterior saludos [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. Subir capturas de pantalla de código [es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).